# Current value changes with contour values in SIESTA

Tags: siesta, electronic-transport

My question is related to the topic solved here: [DOS calculation with TBTrans](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10256/dos-calculation-with-tbtrans)

Here, in the answer, the imaginary contour manipulation is proposed to smooth the DOS. I noticed, however, that doing this would change (in the order of the microA) the value of the current calculated in TBTrans.

I would expect this to happen; however, I would consider the correct value (or the most accurate) the one calculated at the smallest eta possible for the electrodes and 0eV for the device. Would this be correct?

In case needed, this is the input file.

```
# -- NAME & LABEL --

SystemName bnc 
SystemLabel bnc

    # -- MATERIAL --

NumberOfSpecies 1
NumberOfAtoms 152

%block Chemical_Species_label
1 6 C
%endblock Chemical_Species_label

    # -- CELL-ATOMIC-POSITION --

LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang

%block LatticeVectors
        8.5893001556         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000        26.4589004517         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        47.1099014282
%endblock LatticeVectors

AtomicCoordinatesFormat      Ang
%block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
...
%endblock  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

    # -- MONKHORST-PACK --

%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
6   0   0   0.0
0   1   0   0.0
0   0   3   0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack

Diag.ParallelOverK   T


       # --BASIS SET DEFINITION-- #

PAO.BasisSize DZP
PAO.SplitType Split
PAO.SoftDefault true
PAO.SoftPotential 40.0 Ry
PAO.SoftInnerRadius 0.9

PAO.EnergyShift 10 meV

%block PAO.Basis                 # Define Basis set
C        2                # We include 4 shells
n=2 0 2 S 0.3
0.000 0.000
1.000 1.000
n=2 1 2 S 0.3  P 1
0.000 0.000
1.000 1.000
%endblock PAO.Basis

    # -- MOLECULAR DYNAMICS-CONJUGATE-GRADIENT-METHOD --

MD.TypeOfRun            CG  
MD.NumCGsteps           0   
MD.MaxForceTol          0.02 eV/Ang
MD.VariableCell         F
Constant.Volume     T
MD.UseSaveXV            T
MD.UseSaveCG        T
MD.MaxStressTol         0.0010 eV/Ang**3
WriteMDHistory          T 
WriteMDXMol         T
MD.MaxDispl           0.1 Bohr
SCF.MustConverge true

    # -- SPIN FIELD --

SpinPolarized       F       #If spin polarized the use T

    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD --

Mesh.Cutoff     400 Ry
XC.functional           GGA
XC.authors              PBE
MaxSCFIterations        5000
SolutionMethod          transiesta
     
        
    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD-MIXING --

SCF.Mixer.Weight            0.1
SCF.Mixer.History       6
SCF.DM.Tolerance        1.d-5
SCF.FreeE.Converge   T
SCF.FreeE.Tolerance     1.d-5 eV
SCF.Mix.AfterConvergence F
SCF.H.Converge true
SCF.H.Tolerance 1.d-5 eV
DM.FormattedFiles       F
DM.FormattedOutput      F

#####################TRANSIESTA###################

TS.Voltage    0.00000 eV

TBT.k [300 1 1]
 
%block TS.ChemPots
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.ChemPots
 
%block TS.ChemPot.Left
  mu V/2
  contour.eq
    begin
      c-Left
      t-Left
    end
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Left
%block TS.ChemPot.Right
  mu -V/2
  contour.eq
    begin
      c-Right
      t-Right
    end
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Right
 
TS.Elecs.Bulk true
TS.Elecs.DM.Update cross-terms
TS.Elecs.GF.ReUse true
%block TS.Elecs
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.Elecs
 
%block TS.Elec.Left
  HS ./electrode.TSHS
  chem-pot Left
  semi-inf-dir -a3
  elec-pos begin 1
%endblock TS.Elec.Left
 
%block TS.Elec.Right
  HS ./electrode.TSHS
  chem-pot Right
  semi-inf-dir +a3
  elec-pos end -1
%endblock TS.Elec.Right
 
TS.Contours.Eq.Pole 2.5 eV
%block TS.Contour.c-Left
  part circle
   from  -40.00000 eV + V/2 to -10. kT + V/2
    points 30
     method g-legendre
%endblock TS.Contour.c-Left
%block TS.Contour.t-Left
  part tail
   from prev to inf
    points 10
     method g-fermi
%endblock TS.Contour.t-Left
%block TS.Contour.c-Right
  part circle
   from  -40.00000 eV - V/2 to -10. kT - V/2
    points 30
     method g-legendre
%endblock TS.Contour.c-Right
%block TS.Contour.t-Right
  part tail
   from prev to inf
    points 10
     method g-fermi
%endblock TS.Contour.t-Right
 
TS.Elecs.Eta    0.0001000000 eV
%block TS.Contours.nEq
  neq
%endblock TS.Contours.nEq
%block TS.Contour.nEq.neq
  part line
   from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
    delta 0.01 eV
     method mid-rule
%endblock TS.Contour.nEq.neq
 
 
 
# TBtrans options
 
TBT.Elecs.Eta    0.0001 eV
TBT.DOS.Gf T
#TBT.DOS.A T
 
%block TBT.Contours
  neq
%endblock TBT.Contours
 
%block TBT.Contour.neq
  part line
   from   -2.00000 eV to    2.00000 eV
    delta    0.026 eV
     method mid-rule
%endblock TBT.Contour.neq

TBT.BTD.Pivot.Device atom+Left
```

Comment: You have already asked about the eta value in https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/transport-calculations-using-transiesta

Comment: @nickpapior is this question a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Although the other question has many questions in one... I don't know what to do?

Comment: Hi @nickpapior I didn't see your response because you didn't use the @ character to ping me. I've now voted to close the question as a duplicate, since I trust your opinion about Siesta questions!